# How to Transfer selected objects from one JList to another JList in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to transfer the selected objects from one JList to another JList, say List1 and List2.

Comment: put some code with your question that u have tried

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 4):

Here I am showing you example of transferring name of cities from `list` to `list_1`. You will receive output something like this:

[image]

Code for this is :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ListTransfer {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ListTransfer window = new ListTransfer();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ListTransfer() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    String[] values = new String[] {"Surat", "Ahmedabad", "Vadodra", "Anand", "Bharuch", "Maninagar", "Mumbai", "Pune", "Hydrabad", "Banglore"};

    DefaultListModel<Object> model_list = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    DefaultListModel<Object> model_list_1 = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    for (String value : values) {
        model_list.addElement(value);
    }

    JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>();
    list.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    list.setBounds(17, 41, 174, 194);
    list.setModel(model_list);

    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane();
    listScroller.setLocation(15, 43);
    listScroller.setSize(174, 194);
    listScroller.setViewportView(list);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    frame.getContentPane().add(listScroller);

    JList<Object> list_1 = new JList<Object>();
    list_1.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    list_1.setBounds(262, 41, 174, 194);
    list_1.setModel(model_list_1);

    JScrollPane listScroller1 = new JScrollPane();
    listScroller1.setLocation(262, 41);
    listScroller1.setSize(174, 194);
    listScroller1.setViewportView(list_1);
    list_1.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    frame.getContentPane().add(listScroller1);

    JButton shiftbutton = new JButton(">>>");
    shiftbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            list.getSelectedValuesList().stream().forEach((data) -> {
                model_list_1.addElement(data);
                model_list.removeElement(data);
            });
        }
    });
    shiftbutton.setBounds(192, 116, 66, 52);
    frame.getContentPane().add(shiftbutton);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [`JList#getSelectedValuesList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29) (or [`JList#getSelectedValues`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues%28%29) if you're using Java 6 or earlier)

You will then need to apply these values to the second `JList`'s model.  How you do this will depend on the model that you are already using...

Answer (score 0):

as you don't show any code, all I can say is this:

assuming you are using, for example, an arrayList of custom objects as a source of data for each list, you could have a button that when pressed, gets the selected item index, grabs that object and then you add it to the other list.

```
method for the pressed button event (){
    arrayList2.add(arrayList1.get(jList1.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

after this you can just reload the model on jlist2 so it shows the new data.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. it will work fine

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();   
jButtonActionPerformed {
    jList2.setModel(dlm);
    jList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    for (Iterator it = jList1.getSelectedValuesList().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String sel = (String) it.next();
        if (dlm.contains(sel)) {
        } else {
            dlm.addElement(sel);

        }
    }
}
```